# Why won't my function run?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Here are my HTML and JavaScript files. The html file runs properly but the JavaScript file has an error in it and I was wondering why there's an error and how to correct it. I'm trying to draw a flower using user input.

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title> Lab 8: Arrays </title>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
      <script src = "lab8.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body onload = "setup()">
      Number of Petals
      <input id = "text1" type = "text" value = "">
      <br><br>
      Number of Points
      <input id = "text2" type = "text" value = "">
      <br><br>
      <input id = "draw" input type ="button" value="Draw" onclick="draw()">
      <section id = "outputSection"></section>
      <canvas id = "drawingSurface" width = "600" height = "600" style = "border-style: solid"></canvas>
   </body>
</html>
```

javascript :

```
var N, M, r;
var ctx;
var coordinates;
var arr = [];
function setup(){
ctx = document.getElementById("drawingSurface").getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(300,300);
}



function drawShape(){
    var numPetals = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    var numPoints = document.getElementById("text2").value;
    coordinates = getCoordinates(numPetals,NumPoints, 300);
    draw(coordinates);      
}

function GenerateXY(M,N,r){
    coordinates = [[10,10],[20,20]];

    for(var i = 0; i <= M; i += 1){
        var angle = i * 2 * Math.PI / M;
        var r2 = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle * N / 2));
        var x = r2*Math.sin(angle);
        var y = r2*Math.cos(angle);

        coordinates[i] = [x,y];

    }
    return coordinates;
}

function draw(arr){
    ctx = document.getElementById("drawingSurface").getContext("2d");
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=1){
        ctx.lineTo(arr[i][0], arr[i][1]);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
}
```

im having trouble with my last function,(`draw`). the console says it `cannot read property "length"` and I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Where's the `getCoordinates()` function?

Comment: In the code you've shown us `NumPoints` is not defined any where.

Comment: Please don't edit suggested fixes into your question - that is not how this site works.  That makes your question a moving target and ruins the usefulness to others for the answers that people provided.   You can edit your question to clarify things people do not understand or to add more code examples, but NOT to fix things that people have already provided answers on.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML click handler here:

```
<input id = "draw" input type ="button" value="Draw" onclick="draw()">
```

is calling `draw()`, but your function signature is expecting an array to be passed to draw as in `draw(arr)`.  That's why `arr` is not defined so `arr.length` throws an error.

If you mean for `draw()` to just work off the global variable `arr`, then you can remove it from the function definition like this:

```
function draw(){
    ctx = document.getElementById("drawingSurface").getContext("2d");
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=1){
        ctx.lineTo(arr[i][0], arr[i][1]);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
}
```

As a general observation on your code, variables which are used within a function should be declared as local variables with `var` inside the function as in:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("drawingSurface").getContext("2d");
```

This prevents multiple functions from accidentally clobbering each other by using the same global variable for their own private use and prevents the pollution of the global namespace.  It also allows projects to scale and share without conflicts.

Comment: Thanks @jsfriend00, but it sill wont draw my flower and im wondering why?

Comment: @donb - I see you've now edited my answer into your question.  Why did you do that?  You should leave the question as it originally was and then accept answers that fix your problems or comment on answers if they aren't the entire fix.

Comment: @donb - what error do you get now?

Comment: @jsfriend00, okay ill undo the edits, and it doesn't give me any errors however my flower still wont draw..

Comment: @donb - It appears you are calling `draw()` in multiple places and sometimes passing an array and sometimes not.  I have no idea what you really intend to do there, but you have to be consistent.